# Using SwiftUI's .draggable modifier on UIImage

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm making a photo collage app in SwiftUI and I want to add a functionality to move photos between their slots in the collage layout by drag and dropping. I understand the basic principles of the `.draggable` and `.dropDestination` modifiers and I can use it with simple things like strings such as here:

```
struct DraggableStringTestView: View {
    
    @State private var firstString: String = "First 1"
    @State private var secondString: String = "Second 1"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(firstString)
                .background(.white)
                .draggable(firstString)
                .dropDestination(for: String.self) { droppedStrings, location in
                    if droppedStrings[0] != firstString {
                        secondString = firstString
                        firstString = droppedStrings[0]
                    }
                    return true
                }
            Text(secondString)
                .background(.white)
                .draggable(secondString)
                .dropDestination(for: String.self) { droppedStrings, location in
                    if droppedStrings[0] != secondString {
                        firstString = secondString
                        secondString = droppedStrings[0]
                    }
                    return true
                }
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to implement it into my actual use where I need it to work with UIImage and how to make it conform to Transferable protocol. This is my current code:

```
struct CollagePage {
    let id: Int
    var selectedLayout: Int = 1
    var images: [Int: UIImage] = [:]
}

struct PhotoPlaceholderView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: EditorViewModel
    var pageID: Int
    var photoIndex: Int
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(vm.pages[pageID]?.images[photoIndex] == nil ? Color.gray : Color.clear)
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
            .overlay(
                Image(uiImage: vm.pages[pageID]?.images[photoIndex] ?? UIImage())
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            )
            .clipped()
            .onTapGesture {
                vm.activeImageIndex = photoIndex
                vm.isMultipleSelection = false
                vm.isImagePickerPresented = true
            }
    }
}

struct EditorView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = EditorViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: viewModel.addPage) {
                Text("Add New Page")
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .padding()

            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.pages.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
                    VStack {
                        Text("Page \(key)")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding()

                        LayoutSingleSquare(vm: viewModel, pageID: key)
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isImagePickerPresented) {
            PhotoPicker(vm: viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance on this would be very appreciated as I can't figure it out. Ideally I would like to use the .draggable and .dropDestination approach rather than .onDrag .onDrop along with DropDelagate. Thank you

Comment: Which view do you want to drag, and which view do you want to be a drop destination? Why do you "need it to work with UIImage"? SwiftUI `Image` is already `Transferable`, so just convert to a `Image`.

Comment: In the PhotoPlaceholderView I want the `Image(uiImage: vm.pages[pageID]?.images[photoIndex] ?? UIImage())` to be draggable and the `Rectangle()` to be the drop destination. I thought using `Image(uiImage:)` already converts it to `Image`, but then what do I use as `payload:`? Everything I try gives me Cannot conform to Transferable error.

Comment: You have to write `Image(uiImage: vm.pages[pageID]?.images[photoIndex] ?? UIImage())` again as the payload. You can extract a `let` constant and say `image.draggable(image)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI `Image` is `Transferable`, and you already created an `Image`. You can just reuse that.

```
.overlay {
    let image = Image(uiImage: vm.pages[pageID]?.images[photoIndex] ?? UIImage())
    image
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .draggable(image)
}
```